# ST-Link V2 - Firmware Update Error

Tags: stm32, firmware, st-link, update

I purchased a few ST-LINK V2 debuggers / programmers and they were all clones as expected but I was only able to update a single one past V2.J17.S4. For the rest, I just get the error attached. However, I can downgrade the firmware and update them again back to V2.J17.S4.

Attached are images of the guts of the working and not working ST-LINKS. The only difference I can see is the processor is "STM32F102 R8T6 9924H 93 MYS 99 925" for the not working and "STM32F102 R8T6 990AX 98 MYS 99 531" for the working. I am unsure what the differences in these processors are or if this is even the cause.

Any ideas on how I could get the update working would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image][image]

[image][image]

Comment: They are clones. Why would there be any need for clones to work with the firmware of the original product? The original most likely has a F103 with 128k flash while your clones have F102 with 64k flash. If you want an ST-Link, buy an ST-Link, not clones.

Comment: Look at the images above, please. What about the F102 that does work? This is what is creating a lot of confusion for me.

edit: Regarding purchasing a real ST-Link. Unfortunately, I don't make much and I'd still call myself a beginner at this point so hindsight won here.

Comment: The chips seem to have a different silicon revision marking. The other has "3" and the other has "X". I don't know what the difference betweem them is but you can figure it out if you have more time than money. The chips can also be clones of real MCUs as well or otherwise counterfeit. A real ST-Link will just work and save time, many dev boards also have an integrated ST-Link onboard and you can get 2-3 dev boards with price of one separate ST-Link.

Comment: I'll try to find some more information on the chips themselves. If they are indeed clones too, It's probably not worth trying to fix these. Thanks for the suggestion, the discovery and Nucleo boards seem like a good fit for me. I appreciated your time.

Comment: Are they all clones? I have something that looks like the first one... Is it a clone for sure?